# Most detailed surface map that can be produced from LiDAR data in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, lidar, terrain

I want to find old military trenches or at least to get an idea where they were, so that I can go to those areas and survey them.
I know the basic method of conversion from .lasd to elevation raster in ArcMap.

Edit: (For better understanding the process was this: original data was in  .zlas format. I decompressed it using EzLAS application. Then I run the tool in ArcMap to create LAS dataset file, where I selected only (ticked only) Last return. After that I run the tool - LAS dataset to RASTER. After this I also created hillshade from DEM file.)

I got this result:

[image]
The red arrows show a trench, which is clearly visible on LiDAR.

[image]
Same trench but shown as a polyline, since it's not possible to spot it on ortophotoes.

But as you can see on the first picture, there are a lot of small artefacts on the surface. Is this noise? Can it be avoided or eliminated somehow?
This is what I am looking for. A method to show me best possible result.

Comment: That's really dependent on where your data are located, whether they are classified, what point spacing is like, how much noise is in the original data, etc. And sometimes "most detailed" is not always best if that includes noisy data that introduces false highs/lows.

Comment: You don't even say which country you want to find trenches in...

Comment: Can you please give a little more information. LiDAR might be (or not) available for the area of interest.

Comment: Sorry, did not have enough time to formulate the question. I have LiDAR data and I know how to perform conversion to DEM, but since I am not an advanced user of GIS, I am looking for help to get an idea, which method gives the best result.

Comment: You don't mention what kind of data you have but if it is point cloud data  you could view those in CloudCompare.  https://www.danielgm.net/cc/

Comment: All data is in .las format. And will try it in CloudCompare. Thanks for this suggestion.

Comment: Here's a chart of the different QL levels used by the USGS for LiDAR.  It will give you some idea of the different factors that affect LiDAR accuracy. https://www.usgs.gov/3d-elevation-program/topographic-data-quality-levels-qls  You will need to look at similar information that comes with your LiDAR data to decide how accurate it appears to be.  But of course you won't know if any particular artifact is "noise" or real without going on site and looking at some of them.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include details on how you generated the DEM?